# Update the background color index of a range on Change event

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to make Excel VBA event which will fire once a value is entered in a range.

So the range in Column A to Column AS. If I enter a value in column A2 it will update the background color index to the range (A2:AS2).

The below code is firing for all the rows and columns.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Target.Value <> "" Then
        currentRow = Target.Row
        ActiveSheet.Range("A" & curRow & ":AS" & curRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
            'Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Use Option Explicit. `currentRow` and `curRow`?? Surprised the code doesn't error but there you go.

Comment: @SJR thanks for raising the error, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use intersect to check if the `Target` range is in your desired range eg Column A

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("A")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value <> "" Then
            curRow = Target.Row
            Target.Parent.Range("A" & curRow & ":AS" & curRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                'Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Avoid using `ActiveSheet` use `Target.Parent` instead. ActiveSheet can be a different sheet and is not necessarily the sheet where target is in.

Alternatively use `Target.Resize`:

```
Target.Resize(ColumnSize:=45).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
```

So you end up with:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("A")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value <> "" Then
            Target.Resize(ColumnSize:=45).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Getting error on Interset line. "Sub or function is not defined"

Comment: @MonikaRai because it is `Intersect` not `Interset`. Check your typo.

Comment: @PEh it's working, though it's columns, not column. thanks!!

Comment: Please see my comment above.